# ANT: Setting property does not work?

Tags: ant, properties, foreach, var

I try to parse a ini file into properties which I can use in my ant script. I have the following:

```
<project name="DeployScript" default="deploy-staging" basedir=".">
    <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties" />

    <!-- The location of the settings.ini file -->
    <property name="ini-file" location="../settings.ini" />

    <loadfile property="iniConfig" srcFile="${ini-file}"/>  

    <target name="deploy-staging" 
        description="Deploy project to staging environment" >
        <echo message="Ini file: ${ini-file}" />
        <echo message="${lib}" />
        <echo message="${store_dir}" />
        <echo message="${ant.home}" />

        <!--- walk the ini file's lines -->
        <foreach list="${iniConfig}"
            target="echoMsg"
            param="line" 
            delimiter="${line.separator}" />

        <echo message="HERE: ${prevSection}" />
    </target>

    <property name="prevSection" value="" />

    <!-- this is executed for every line in the ini file. -->
    <target name="echoMsg">  
        <!-- strip out the section name, variable name and value (if exists on the line) -->
        <propertyregex property="secm"
            input="${line}"
            regexp="^\[(.*)\]"
            select="\1"
            casesensitive="false" />
        <propertyregex property="name"
            input="${line}"
            regexp="^([\S]+)\s*=\s*([^;]+)"
            select="\1"
            casesensitive="false"
            defaultValue="" /> 
        <propertyregex property="value"
            input="${line}"
            regexp="^([\S]+)\s*=\s*([^;]+)"
            select="\2"
            casesensitive="false"
            defaultValue="" />

        <!-- overwrite the previous section if we have found a new one. -->
        <if>
            <isset property="secm" />
            <then>
                <echo message="PREVSECTION IS SET" />   
                <property name="prevSection" value="${secm}" />
            </then>
        </if>

        <!-- display the information about the found data -->       
        <echo message="line    = ${line}" />
        <echo message="section = ${secm}" />
        <echo message="name    = ${name}" />        
        <echo message="value   = ${value}" />
        <echo message="new last section: ${prevSection}" />
        <echo message="----" />             
    </target>   
</project>
```

What I try to do is parse all name=value pairs and put them in properties like: section.name=value;

Somehow the section is not remembered within the "echoMsg" target. I would like the section name to be remembered.

So,

```
[global]
name=var
name2=val

[section2]
name=var
```

Should become:

```
global.name=var
global.name2=val
section2.name=var
```

This is the output of my ant script:

```
echoMsg:
 [echo] PREVSECTION IS SET
 [echo] line    = [global]
 [echo] section = global
 [echo] name    =
 [echo] value   =
 [echo] new last section: global
 [echo] ----

echoMsg:
 [echo] line    = servername = my-server.local ; Server name
 [echo] section = ${secm}
 [echo] name    = servername
 [echo] value   = mac-mini-van-Peter.local7
 [echo] new last section: ${prevSection}
 [echo] ----
```

As you can see, the last "${prevSection}" is not set. I would expect it to be "global".

I tried to use  instead of property, but there's no difference.

Comment: Try using the [`<echoproperties>`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/echoproperties.html) task after you read in the INI file. This will list all of the properties, and you can see what's actually being set as a property in Ant. That might help you see where the error is. I've never used an INI file in Ant, so I'm not sure how it's read in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a hint: Try adding an echo section before the `<propertyregex>` statements to see what the values of the various properties.

I added these `<echo>` lines...

```
<target name="echoMsg">
    <!-- strip out the section name, variable name and value (if exists on the line) -->
    <echo message="prev line    = ${line}" />
    <echo message="prev section = ${secm}" />
    <echo message="prev name    = ${name}" />
    <echo message="prev value   = ${value}" />
    <echo message="prev new last section: ${prevSection}" />
    <echo message="----" />
```

Now let's look at the output:

```
deploy-staging:
     [echo] Ini file: /Users/david/property.ini
     [echo] ${lib}
     [echo] ${store_dir}
     [echo] /usr/share/ant

echoMsg:
     [echo] prev line    = [global]
     [echo] prev section = ${secm}
     [echo] prev name    = ${name}
     [echo] prev value   = ${value}
     [echo] prev new last section: 
     [echo] ----
     [echo] PREVSECTION IS SET
     [echo] line    = [global]
     [echo] section = global
     [echo] name    = 
     [echo] value   = 
     [echo] new last section: 
     [echo] ----

echoMsg:
     [echo] prev line    = name=foo
     [echo] prev section = ${secm}
     [echo] prev name    = ${name}
     [echo] prev value   = ${value}
     [echo] prev new last section: 
     [echo] ----
     [echo] line    = name=foo
     [echo] section = ${secm}
     [echo] name    = name
     [echo] value   = foo
     [echo] new last section: 
     [echo] ----

echoMsg:
     [echo] prev line    = name2=bar
     [echo] prev section = ${secm}
     [echo] prev name    = ${name}
     [echo] prev value   = ${value}
     [echo] prev new last section: 
     [echo] ----
     [echo] line    = name2=bar
     [echo] section = ${secm}
     [echo] name    = name2
     [echo] value   = bar
     [echo] new last section: 
     [echo] ----

echoMsg:
     [echo] prev line    = [section2]
     [echo] prev section = ${secm}
     [echo] prev name    = ${name}
     [echo] prev value   = ${value}
     [echo] prev new last section: 
     [echo] ----
     [echo] PREVSECTION IS SET
     [echo] line    = [section2]
     [echo] section = section2
     [echo] name    = 
     [echo] value   = 
     [echo] new last section: 
     [echo] ----

echoMsg:
     [echo] prev line    = name=fubar
     [echo] prev section = ${secm}
     [echo] prev name    = ${name}
     [echo] prev value   = ${value}
     [echo] prev new last section: 
     [echo] ----
     [echo] line    = name=fubar
     [echo] section = ${secm}
     [echo] name    = name
     [echo] value   = fubar
     [echo] new last section: 
     [echo] ----
     [echo] HERE: 

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 1 second
```

Each call to `<echomsg>` loses the values previously set in `<echomsg>`.

I suggest you try the `<for>` task. The `<for>` task won't lose the values of your property through each iteration of the loop. However, you'll have to add the `override` setting to your `<propertyregex>` tasks, and to use the `<var>` tasks instead of `<property>` tasks to be able to reset your property values through each iteration of the loop.

You'll also have to change your `<taskdef>` to this:

```
<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml" />
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the code which works for me. Just wanted to share with the WWW:

```
<project name="DeployScript" default="deploy-staging" basedir=".">
    <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml" />

    <!-- The location of the settings.ini file -->
    <property name="ini-file" location="../settings.ini" />

    <!-- load the ini file -->
    <loadfile property="iniConfig" srcFile="${ini-file}"/>  

    <!-- when no section is given, the vars are stored in the "default" section -->
    <var name="theSection" value="default" />

    <!-- set global properties for this build -->
    <target name="deploy-staging" description="" >

        <echo message="Start parsing ini file" level="info" />

        <!--
            PARSE INI FILE
            This section parses the ini file and creates the parameters
            which we can use in this script. 
        -->
        <for list="${iniConfig}" param="line" delimiter="${line.separator}" trim="true">
            <sequential>

                <propertyregex property="newSection" input="@{line}" regexp="^\[(.*)\]" select="\1" casesensitive="false" defaultvalue="" override="true" />
                <propertyregex property="name" input="@{line}" regexp="^([^;][\S]+)\s*=\s*([^;]+)" select="\1" casesensitive="false" defaultValue="" override="true" /> 
                <propertyregex property="value" input="@{line}" regexp="^([^;][\S]+)\s*=\s*([^;]+)" select="\2" casesensitive="false"  defaultValue="" override="true" />

                <if>
                    <!-- if we recieved a new section -->
                    <isset property="newSection" />
                    <then>
                        <if>
                            <!-- section is not empty -->
                            <not><equals arg1="${newSection}" arg2="" /></not>
                            <then>
                                <!-- store this as the new section --> 
                                <var name="theSection" value="${newSection}" />
                            </then>
                        </if>                       
                    </then>
                </if>

                <!-- only create a new var if we have a var-name -->
                <if>
                    <isset property="name" />
                    <then>
                        <if>
                            <!-- name is not empty -->
                            <not><equals arg1="${name}" arg2="" /></not>
                            <then>
                                <!-- store this as the new section --> 
                                <var name="${theSection}.${name}" value="${value}" /> 
                                <echo message="${theSection}.${name} = ${value}" level="info" />
                            </then>
                        </if>                       
                    </then>
                </if>
            </sequential>
        </for>
    </target>

</project>
```